# Dropping rows based on unique ID's in a single column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a csv into a dataframe and I am looking to drop rows based on a list of unique ID's.

```
Name     Song_ID     Status
song 1   12345       Pending
song 1   12345       Validating
song 2   18284       Validating
song 3   17385       Pending
song 3   17385       Pending
song 4   13467       Pending
song 5   19999       Pending
song 5   19999       Pending
```

For this example, I would like to drop the rows with Song_ID's: 12345, 17385, 19999

Any tips/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `isin`, get a mask, and then index into `df`.

Comment: @coldspeed, with all my respect, how is the "dup" related to the question? I bet you did not read it carefully.

Comment: @DyZ he's not dropping duplicates, he dropping songs with specific ids.

Comment: @user3483203 Oops.

Comment: @DyZ though it's possible they specifically mentioned those 3 unique IDs because there exist more than one of those. Whose to say.